# On mouseout button disables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I am new so please forgive me if I sound stupid.

So I am trying to make it so on mouse out the button disables. Here is what I tried so far: (***Thanks in advance!***)

```
function alertonclick() {
  alert("You got me! GG. At least I tried.");
}    
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}      

    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
          document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("button").value = "BUTTON IS DISABLED";
                document.getElementById("button").style.background='808080';

                }
    });
```

HTML

```
<button id="button" tabindex="-1" onclick="alertonclick()" class="Rainbow buttonmove notouch button1 btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: I did add all of it.

Comment: Where does `addEvent` get called? And by disabled, do you just mean the color is changed or truly not interactive?

Comment: oh wait i forgot to add something!

Comment: @ScottMarcus When I mean disabled I mean color changed and not interactive.

Comment: And where's `alertonclick`?

Comment: Hi, check the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event

Comment: Your mouseout function is being added to the document, not the button.

Comment: @user1599011 So how do I fix it?

Comment: Add the event listener to the button instead.

Comment: @user1599011 could you give me the code for it?

Comment: replace `document` with `document.getElementById("button")`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP keeps stating different requirements for what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first your entire `addEvent` function is not needed unless you suspect that you may have users using Internet Explorer 8! All browsers since IE 9 (1995) support `.addEventListener()`.

You also don't need: `e = e ? e : window.event;` for the same reason.

Next, [you shouldn't be using inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) like `onclick` as they are a legacy approach to working with events from 25+ years ago and only persist today because people just see someone else use them and copy/paste them without understanding why they shouldn't be used. Separate your JavaScript from your HTML and use `.addEventListener()` which you actually do use in your `addEvent` function.

You're attempt at setting the color isn't right because you didn't add "#" in front of the hex code, which identifies it as a hexadecimal color.

Finally, if you want to be able to interact with the button when the mouse goes back over it, then you really don't want to disable the button (because then you wouldn't fire a `mouseover` event when the mouse went back to it).

So really, much of your code isn't needed. The essence is this:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("button")

btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  this.textContent = "BUTTON IS DISABLED";
  this.classList.add("disabled");
});

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  this.textContent = "BUTTON ENABLED";
  this.classList.remove("disabled");
});
```

```css
.disabled { background-color:#808080; }
```

```html
<button id="button" tabindex="-1" class="Rainbow buttonmove notouch button1 btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: I wanted the button to disable and turn grey when the mouse leaves and for it to also turn grey. Not onclick!

Comment: @SamiOsman You are not being clear. You've said that you do want to interact with it when the mouse is over it, so it has to be clickable.

Comment: No, I didn't say that! I said on mouse leave/mouseout button to disable and (optional) turn grey,

Comment: @SamiOsman In the comments above, you said "Like I want to disable when the mouse leaves, ***then re-enable it when the mouse comes back***."

Comment: Yes, this is better but (I hope I'm not too much) for it to re-enable not on hover but on re-enter

Comment: @SamiOsman The issue is that if you disable the button, then moving the mouse back over it later will not cause the `mouseover` event to fire (because it's disabled), so you can't re-enable it that way. And, when you re-enter, you are hovering.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that when you leave it you don't want it to be interactive, but when you come back to it you do. That's exactly what my answer shows. There's no need to formally disable it, only style it because when you leave it, you can't click it, so you don't have to worry about disabling it.

Comment: I meant when you go to the address bar, or right-click the button disables. but when you stop right-clicking the button is enabled. If you do not understand let us discuss this in the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231799/discussion-between-scott-marcus-and-sami-osman).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

No jquery needed :-)

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the color changes? And when the cursor comes back for the color to change back and the button not disabled anymore?

Comment: Well, if you want to reactivate the button after the cursor is back on it, then what's the point of disabling it?
If you just want its color to change, then css is sufficient for this:

`#button {background-color: #333; color: #fff;}
#button:hover {background-color: #eee; color: #333;}`
*example colors used just to show the change

Comment: Like I want to disable when the mouse leaves, then re-enable it when the mouse comes back. The color change was optional just for a trick. Do you understand?

Comment: if so, duplicate my example code, and replace the event with 'mouseenter' and `setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')` call with `removeAttribute('disabled')` :)